# Raster Function for NDVI Band Calculation - Divide by Zero

Tags: python, numpy, rasterio

I am using rasterio to open image files related to 2 specific bands:

```
b4 = rio.open(r)
b8 = rio.open(poly)
```

I then read the bands into a python array, I think it's a numpy array but not sure?:

```
#Read Red(b4) and NIR(b8) as arrays
red = b4.read()
nir = b8.read()
```

Then I perform band based calculation against them via the following:

```
#Calculate NDVI
ndvi = (nir.astype(float) - red.astype(float)) / (nir + red)
```

Now, this of course can have the denominator (nir + red) be equal to zero, which will cause a divide by zero issue that I believe is messing with the results.

Is there a way to set the instances where the denominator is equal to zero to have a value of -1 or something?  How are you handling those in your own raster functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using numpy to build your raster function, which can handle situations where the denominator is 0.

```
red = np.arange(0, 15).reshape(4,4)
ndvi = np.arange(-10, 6).reshape(4,4)
ndvi = np.divide(np.subtract(red, nir), np.add(red, nir))
ndvi = np.where(ndvi == np.inf, -99, ndvi)
```

numpy returns `np.inf` when dividing by zero, which you can later on replace by any arbitrary number to indicate an invalid NDVI value; in the example -99.

Comment: That's exactly the type of thing I was looking for.  What is your Arrange and Reshape doing there in your example?

Comment: `np.arange` gives a 1-D array starting-stopping at the numbers provided. `reshape` reshapes the 1-D array (shape (16,)) to a 2-Dimensional array (shape(4,4)). See [arange](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html?highlight=arange#numpy.arange) and [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape) documentation. 

If this answers helped you out, please tick 'answered'.

Comment: What was the reasoning behind the numbers you supplied for the parameters in the arrange and reshape calls?

Comment: The reason i ask is b/c just using the divide and where pieces, you still get a RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide.  So I was trying to figure out the reasoning behind choosing the 0,15 and -10, 6 for the arrange calls, and 4,4 for the reshapes?

Comment: I designed the value ranges so that a zero would occur once in the denominator. The `(4, 4)` shape is just to create a 2D array that would easily fit in my python window.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense.  Couldn't figure out where those numbers were coming from and thought they may have had something to do with the ndvi math.  It's much more reassuring that it was just populating sample data.